# Indefinitely move Python turtle while allowing input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've just started working on a version of Snake using Turtle, and I've encountered an issue. I want the snake to move indefinitely, but also to allow the user to move the snake with the keyboard. I got the snake to move from user input, but I can't figure out how to get the snake to keep moving in the same direction while there is no input, whilst preventing it from ignoring user input:

```
while True:
  win.onkey(up,"Up")
  win.onkey(right,"Right")
  win.onkey(down,"Down")
  win.onkey(left,"Left")
  win.listen()
#moves the snake one unit in the same direction it is currently facing
  movesnake()
```

I'm new to Turtle, and this is my guess at how to solve this issue - which obviously doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm conscious Pygame might make this easier but since I've already started with Turtle, I would prefer to get a Turtle solution, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event-driven environment like turtle should never have `while True:` as it potentially blocks out events (e.g. keyboard).  Use an `ontimer()` event instead.

Generally, `onkey()` and `listen()` don't belong in a loop -- for most programs they only need to be called once.

Here's a skeletal example of an autonomous turtle being redirected by user input:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def right():
    snake.setheading(0)

def up():
    snake.setheading(90)

def left():
    snake.setheading(180)

def down():
    snake.setheading(270)

def movesnake():

    snake.forward(1)

    screen.ontimer(movesnake, 100)

snake = Turtle("turtle")

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.onkey(up, "Up")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(down, "Down")

screen.listen()

movesnake()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah thank you so much, that worked perfectly :) the more you know